Need help in using the right-hand rule for cross product

In the $Oxyz$ space, consider two lines $\Delta_1: \dfrac{x-4}{3} = \dfrac{y-1}{-1} = \dfrac{z + 5}{-2}$ and $\Delta_2 = \dfrac{x-2}{1} = \dfrac{y +3}{3} = \dfrac{z}{1}.$ Suppose $M \in \Delta_1, N \in \Delta_2$ such that $MN$ is the common perpendicular of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2.$ Find $\vec{MN}.$

This is the solution from the textbook:
Let $M = (4 + 3m; 1 - m; -5 - 2m)$ and $N = (2 + n; -3 + 3n; n)$
$\implies \vec{MN} = (-2 + n - 3m; -4 + 3n + m; 5 + n + 2m).$
$\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}(3; -1, -2)$ and $\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}(1; 3; 1)$ are the direction vectors of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2,$ respectively.
$\implies\vec{MN} = k(\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}\times\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}) = k(5; - 5; 10) \implies m = -1, n = 1 \implies \vec{MN} = (2; -2; 4)$
This is my approach:
$A(4; 1; -5) \in \Delta_1$ and $B(2; -3; 0) \in \Delta_2 \implies \vec{AB} = (-2; -4; 5)$
$\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}(3; -1, -2)$ and $\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}(1; 3; 1)$ are the direction vectors of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2,$ respectively.
$\implies\vec{MN} = k(\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}\times\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}) = k(5; - 5; 10) = k'(1; -1; 2) \implies MN = |k'|\sqrt{6}$
On the other hand, $MN = d(\Delta_1, \Delta_2) = \dfrac{|(\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}\times\vec{u_{\Delta_2}})\cdot\vec{AB}|}{|\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}\times\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}|} = 2\sqrt{6} \implies k' = \pm2.$
At this point, I needed to decide the sign of $k'$. I'm aware that the right-hand rule might help in this case, but I'm not very well-versed in this rule so I believe I have applied it incorrectly. Since I believe we could find an orientation where $\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}$ takes the index finger and $\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}$ takes the middle finger, the cross-product vector will point in the direction of the thumb. But since $M \in \Delta_1$ and $N \in \Delta_2,$ $\vec{MN}$ will point in the opposite direction, which implies $k' = -2$ and $\vec{MN} = (-2; 2; -4).$ What is incorrect in my reasoning? How could I find the sign of $k'$?
Thank you!



since $M \in \Delta_1$ and $N \in \Delta_2,$ $\vec{MN}$ will point in the opposite direction. Can you explain this?

@Morten Hi, I just added another picture to illustrate my reasoning behind that. Please have a look. Thank you!

Why did you conclude $k'=-2$ from this?

@Morten I reasoned that because $\vec{MN} = k(\vec{u_{\Delta_1}}\times\vec{u_{\Delta_2}}) = k (5; -5; 10) = k'(1; -1; 2),$ $\vec{MN}$ will point in the same direction as the vector cross product if $k' >0$ and in the opposite direction if $k <0.$ Since the image suggests that the cross product vector and $\vec{MN}$ point in opposite directions so I concluded that $k' < 0$

It's not good to draw it in 2-dimensional space. This is not the case if you imagine it in 3-dimensional.

I will do this in this way: write MN in a parametric expression like the solution and then take the dot product with $u_1$ and $u_2$ to get $m$ and $n$, this is an efficient method. If doing this using your method, it's tough to determine the direction, also, without rigorous proof.

One way to find $\vec{MN}$ is to take the two candidates
(each in the opposite direction of the other) and check to see which one is in the direction from $M$ to $N.$
Consider the plane $\pi_2$ orthogonal to $\vec{MN}$ and passing through the line $\Delta_2.$
Note that line $\Delta_1$ is parallel to the plane $\pi_2$,
so if we translate the segment
$\overline{AB}$ so that $A$ maps to a point still on $\Delta_1,$
then $B$ will map to a point still on $\pi_2.$
Therefore if we translate $A$ to $M,$ the same translation translates $B$ to a point $P$ on plane $\pi_2.$
Since this is a translation, $\vec{MP} = \vec{AB}.$
But it should also be clear that the angle between $\vec{MP}$ and $\vec{MN}$
is less than a right angle, because these two vectors describe the directions from a single point not on the plane $\pi_2$ to two points on $\pi_2,$
with one of the vectors being perpendicular to the plane.
Therefore we have the following fact about the dot product of these vectors:
$$ \vec{MN} \cdot \vec{AB} = \vec{MN} \cdot \vec{MP} > 0. $$
You have two candidates for $\vec{MN}.$ Take the dot product of one candidate with $\vec{AB}.$ If the result is positive, this candidate is $\vec{MN}.$
If the result is negative, this candidate is $-\vec{MN}$
and the other candidate is $\vec{MN}.$
In the exercise you are doing,
$$ (−2;2;−4) \cdot (−2;−4;5) = 4 - 8 - 20 = -24 < 0, $$
and therefore the correct answer is $-(−2;2;−4),$
that is, $\vec{MN} = (2;-2;4).$

Thank you very much! That's very clever! I have one question to make sure I understand your reasoning correctly. When I sketched out your idea, I found that the reason that the angle between $\vec{MP}$ and $\vec{MN}$ is less than a right angle is that these two vectors describe the directions from a single point not on the plane $\pi_2$ to two points on $\pi_2$ (as you said) and that one of these vectors is perpendicular to $\pi_2,$ right? I think without the last condition, the angle may be greater than a right angle. Please let me know what you think!

You are correct. The fact that one vector is perpendicular to the plane is essential. Otherwise we cannot know that the angle is less than a right angle. I have added this condition to the answer.

Thank you very much again!
